# How to Achieve this $letters(*) with re Module in Python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

**I'm a total begginner when it comes to Regex** , if any one has a suggestion for a good place to learn more about re Module, I would realy appreciate it .

As for my question , Basically i'm playing around with it to find something like this :

```
$letters(content)
```

- no \s or \t between **$** and **letters**
- letters are either **UPPER** or **LOWER** or **_** or **Numbers** (But not at start)
- Possible \s or \t between **letters** and **(**
- Must Ends with **)**

As for **content** :

- can Have : **UPPERCASE** , **LOWERCAE** , **DIGIT** , **$letter2(..)**, **'word'**, **"word"** , **,** , **+-*/%!** , **.**

You can Imagine it as a Function Calling in this case i guess .

so in Brief , How can i achieve finding such Prototypes :

```
$Operation(10, $l_shift_byte($random(20)), "addition")
```

or

```
$MessageBox(0, "Hello There Bug Boi !\nYour Lucky Number is : "+ $toString((10 - $random(20))), MB_OK)
```

**---------- [ EDIT / UPDATE ] ----------**

**what i tried (From what Stefan Said ):**

`^(\s+\$|\$)[A-Za-z_]+(.*)`

which works fine but as long as there are no \n inside the ( .. )
example of a not working case where the match stops at \n :

```
$operation( 10, $l_shift_byte($random(20)), "\naddition")
```

**Also Kept Messing with it and got to this :**

`^(\s+\$[A-Za-z_]+|\$[A-Za-z_]+)[0-9A-Za-z_]+(\s+\(|\()[\w\W]+(\)|\)\s)$`

which Also not working as expected , for example if i try to match this :

`$ThisIsATest() $operatio8n_s   ( 10, $l_shift_byte($random(20)), " \naddition")$quit()`

it Returns everything , since it starts with $acceptable_ch4ars ( ... and ends with )  , **wherase** it should returns :

```
[
    '$ThisIsATest()',
    '$operatio8n_s   ( 10, $l_shift_byte($random(20)), " \naddition")',
    '$quit()'
]
```

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is always the documentation of the module [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

Coming to your case, a possible regex is:

```
^\$[A-Za-z]+\(.*\)
```

which finds both of your example strings.

- `^`: matches the start of the string (you might want to remove this)
- `\$`: matches the `$`, note that it is escaped using `\`
- `[A-Za-z]+`: matches 1 or more lower or upper case letters
- `\(` and `\)`: match the enclosing brackets
- `.*`: Matches everything except newline 0 or more times

When it comes to regex, [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/) might become handy.

Comment: Pretty usefull Link , And very Well explained ! Thank you very much . From what you explained I managed to optimize it a little and This is what i ended up with **^.\s\$|\$+[A-Za-z]+\(.*\)** Works pretty fine , Thank you ! Waiting in case there are some more detailed Answers .

Comment: Both regex are working when I try them (with python3). After importing `re` I use `re.match(regex,test_string).group(0)` to show the entire match.

Comment: Can you check this : [PY3_CODE](https://onlinegdb.com/Bycd1HCzD) , it works fine but once i add \n or some spaces it does not , How ever it works fine in that TestingRegex Website .

Comment: I would split the string by newline, loop over the individual lines and check if those match your pattern.

Comment: You can also remove the `^` which actually matches the start of the string, since the string from your link starts with a whitespace and not with a `$` there is no match. I updated my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: I know  but the main problem is on things such as : `$operation( 10, $l_shift_byte($random(20)), "\naddition")`   notice the \n in that string ? well that a problem Because the match stops right there Unless  i replace it first with some special char then try to match the regex and put \n back (which actually works ).... But thats a bit much thing to do in my case .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220253/discussion-between-saad-amrani-and-stefan).

Comment: Remove the `^` in the regex I gave and I think it does what you want...

Comment: Not working buddy , ^ is not a problem  , i managed to work it out so it matches either it  with $ or \s+\$  , please read well what i said in my last comment , Untill we found a solution i'm accepting further answers .

Comment: Ok, then please specify better in your question what you actually want to have instead of coming up with new stuff every time you comment. The answer I provided matches all the strings you gave in your question...

Comment: Stefan , My bad I forgot about that ,
I updated it , please give some time to it and check it out  .
Thanks.